# Linking C with C++

Tags: c++, c, wrapper

I have a open source C project and if I try to execute examples it is working fine but if i try to call those functions from C++ by using extern (including all headers with function definition) it is throwing error undefined reference to function_name. Can someone help me out how to properly wrap the C code using C++ and calling functions directly from C++ by just including headers of C?

Answer (score 4):

You need `extern "C"` [language linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) to declare C functions in your C++ code.

This (among other things) prevents the [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) otherwise used by the C++ compiler for functions.

Commonly `extern "C"` is added using *conditional compilation* in header files by checking the existence of the `__cplusplus` macro:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// Function declarations

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // End of the extern "C" block
#endif
```

Comment: I would point out that `extern "C"` is not at all about preventing name mangling because implying that it has anything to do with name mangling seems to have been giving people the wrong ideas for far too long. What `extern "C"` is really all about is doing whatever C would do. [On some platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=vs-2019#FormatC), doing whatever C would do actually still involves name mangling…